# VBA Sheets delete

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a lot of worksheets. I wrote a macro which deletes a few worksheets but Excel asks me if I'm sure that I want to delete it every time. Is there any way to excel not ask about it every time? It definitely extends the work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Off-Topic: `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.`

Comment: Please provide any research into this, what you have tried already, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help you. I found the answer [here](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-worksheet/)

Credit goes to analysistabs.com team.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub sbDeleteASheet()
'Stopping Application Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts=FALSE
Sheet1.Delete
'OR You can mention the Sheet name
Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
'Enabling Application alerts once we are done with our task
Application.DisplayAlerts=TRUE
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE before deleting.

Comment: Wrong way - you need to set it to **`False`** to stop it displaying alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty easy, you just have to set the screen updating to false!
Don't forget to set it to true again at the end. Do something like this:

```
sub calc()
''turn off screen updating and displaying alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

code

''turn on screen updating and displaying alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

end sub
```

Comment: Nope, it's not `ScreenUpdating`.  That just stops the screen refreshing and you'll still get asked.  It's just the `DisplayAlerts` that stops the question.  If you avoid things like `Select` you generally don't need to use `ScreenUpdating=False`.